# Using mutable to allow modification of object in unordered_set

Tags: c++, mutable, unordered-set

Please consider the following [code](https://ideone.com/sz9jO0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

struct MyStruct
{
    int x, y;
    double mutable z;

    MyStruct(int x, int y)
        : x{ x }, y{ y }, z{ 0.0 }
    {
    }
};

struct MyStructHash
{
    inline size_t operator()(MyStruct const &s) const
    {
        size_t ret = s.x;
        ret *= 2654435761U;
        return ret ^ s.y;
    }
};

struct MyStructEqual
{
    inline bool operator()(MyStruct const &s1, MyStruct const &s2) const
    {
        return s1.x == s2.x && s1.y == s2.y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<MyStruct, MyStructHash, MyStructEqual> set;
    auto pair = set.emplace(100, 200);

    if (pair.second)
        pair.first->z = 300.0;

    std::cout << set.begin()->z;
}
```

I am using `mutable` to allow modification of the member `z` of `MyStruct`. I would like to know if this is ok and legal, since the set is a) unordered and b) I am not using `z` for hashing or equality?

Comment: Have you considered splitting `MyStruct` to two structs and using them as key/value in `unordered_map`?

Comment: @AndriyTylychko I have other members besides `x`, `y`, `z` and they all kinda interlinked on initialisation, so it would make splitting a little awkward.

Comment: If `x`, `y` and `z` are "interlinked" take a look at Boost.MultiIndex or my Boost.MultiIndex-inspired answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say this is a perfect use of the "Mutable" keyword.

The mutable keyword is there to mark members that are not part of the "state" of the class (ie they are some form of cached or intermediate value that does not represent the logical state of the object).

Your equality operator (as well as other comparators (or any function that serializes the data) (or function that generates a hash)) define the state of the object. Your equality comparitor does not use the member 'z' when it checks the logical state of the object so the member 'z' is not part of the state of the class and is therefore illegable to use the "mutable" accessor.

Now saying that. I do think the code is very brittle to write this way. There is nothing in the class that stops a future maintainer accidentally making z part of the state of the class (ie adding it to the hash function) and thus breaking the pre-conditions of using it in `std::unordered_set<>`. So you should be very judicious in using this and spend a lot of time writing comments and unit tests to make sure the preconditions are maintained.

I would also look into "@Andriy Tylychko" comment about breaking the class into a const part and a value part so that you could potentially use it as part of a `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of thorough answer I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `z` is not part of the state of the object *only* in the context of that particular kind of `unordered_set`. 
If one continues this route one will end up making everything mutable just in case.

In general, what you are asking is not possible because the element hash would need to be recomputed automatically on the modification of the element.

The most general thing you can do is to have a protocol for element modification, similar to the `modify` function in Boost.MultiIndex https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#modify.
The code is ugly, but thanks to the existence of `extract` it can be made fairly efficient when it matters (well, still your particular struct will not benefit from move).

```
template<class UnorderedSet, class It, class F>
void modify(UnorderedSet& s, It it, F f){
    It h = it; ++h;
    auto val = std::move(s.extract(it).value());
    f(val);
    s.emplace_hint(h, std::move(val) );
}

int main(){
    std::unordered_set<MyStruct, MyStructHash, MyStructEqual> set;
    auto pair = set.emplace(100, 200);

    if (pair.second) modify(set, pair.first, [](auto&& e){e.z = 300;});

    std::cout << set.begin()->z;
}
```

(code not tested)

---

@JoaquinMLopezMuños (author of Boost.MultiIndex) suggested reinserting the whole node. I think that would work like this:

```
template<class UnorderedSet, class It, class F>
void modify(UnorderedSet& s, It it, F f){
    It h = it; ++h;
    auto node = s.extract(it);
    f(node.value());
    s.insert(h, std::move(node));
}
```

---

**EDIT2**: Final tested code, needs C++17 (for extract)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

struct MyStruct
{
    int x, y;
    double  z;

    MyStruct(int x, int y)
        : x{ x }, y{ y }, z{ 0.0 }
    {
    }

};

struct MyStructHash
{
    inline size_t operator()(MyStruct const &s) const
    {
        size_t ret = s.x;
        ret *= 2654435761U;
        return ret ^ s.y;
    }
};

struct MyStructEqual
{
    inline bool operator()(MyStruct const &s1, MyStruct const &s2) const
    {
        return s1.x == s2.x && s1.y == s2.y;
    }
};

template<class UnorderedSet, class It, class F>
void modify(UnorderedSet& s, It it, F f){
    auto node = s.extract(it++);
    f(node.value());
    s.insert(it, std::move(node));
}

int main(){
    std::unordered_set<MyStruct, MyStructHash, MyStructEqual> set;
    auto pair = set.emplace(100, 200);

    if(pair.second) modify(set, pair.first, [](auto&& e){e.z = 300;});

    std::cout << set.begin()->z;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I would prefer to avoid copying and reinserting element if possible

Comment: @KillzoneKid, note that when it matters nothing should be copied, only moved ;)

Comment: Why aren't you inserting the node back into the container with the `node_type` overload of `std::unordered_set::insert`?

Comment: @JoaquínMLópezMuñoz, because I though that anything that is not part of the value would be discarded anyway. But probably it is a mistake on my part stemming from the fact that I don't know very well how the insertion of a node works, so I did the safer option (in the context of my ignorance). But now I see that this can save all allocations. I wasn't sure if creating that hint was a good idea even. What do you think of the modified code now? Do you think this is a decent solution or B.MI would uses some other technique (by using the extra knowledge that the change doesn't affect the hash?

Comment: @alfC I think this is a decent solution. B.MI is potentially faster (if only marginally) because it checks whether the modified element is already in place without going through the entire insertion procedure --the gain, if any, is likely negligible, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The typical used mutable is to allow a const method to change a data member that does not form part of an object’s fundamental state e.g. a lazily evaluated value derived from the object’s non-mutable data.
 Declaring public data members mutable is not good a practice, you are allowing the objects state to be changed externally even when that object is marked const.

In your example code, you have used mutable because (based on your comment), your code would not compile without it. Your code would not compile because the iterator returned from emplace is const.

There are two incorrect ways to solve this problem, one is the use of the mutable keyword, another, almost as bad, is to cast the const reference into a non-const reference.

The emplace method is intended to construct an object directly into the collection and avoid a copy constructor call. This is a useful optimization but you shouldn’t use it if it will compromise the maintainability of your code. You should either initialize z in your constructor or you should not use emplace to add the object to the set, instead set the value of z and then insert the object into your set.

If your object never needs to change after construction, you should make your class/struct immutable by either declaring them const or declaring the data members private and adding non-mutating accessor methods (these should be declared const).

Comment: That is the affect of adding `mutable`. I would not say that is the "purpose" of mutable. The "purpose" is to indicate to both programmer and compiler that the member is not part of the logical state of the object.

Comment: To the compiler, in this example x & y are equally "mutable". The use of the keyword mutable for z is in my opinion misleading because it implies that x & y are  immutable but the author of the code has done nothing to make them immutable, ie. declaring them const.

Comment: [`mutable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) members of const class instances are modifiable.  This not restricted to use by `const` member functions.

Comment: True, but in this case nothing has been declared const so all members are modifiable. However, in the scope of a const method, the instance is always const.

Comment: Also a method that is not const cannot be called on a const instance so all members would be modifiable. I am not sure what a reasonable use case would be to allow a const object's state to be externally modified or why any externally modified part of an object would not be considered part of its state.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn’t compile without mutable, seems like restriction put on set by the language

Comment: Can you share the error message and the particular compiler you are using?

Comment: The reason is the iterator returned by emplace is a const iterator and therefore the -> operator returns a const reference making your object const when accessed from that iterator. I will revise and expand upon my answer.

Comment: You have a good understanding of the affect of mutable. **BUT** I think you don't understand its intent and what problems it is designed to resolve.

Comment: We clearly have a difference of opinion on the appropriate use of mutable data members in C++. Can you point me to any online article that supports the position that marking public data members mutable is an appropriate use of mutable?  I have not been able to find any.